# AppleScript to return condition depending on audio file length

Tags: macos, applescript, automation, hazel

I'd like to use [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com/) *(a rule-based file system automator)* for macOS to automatically move mixtape audio files from one folder to another, if their duration is longer than 30 minutes.

Hazel doesn't provide a built-in method of checking for audio file length (that I know of), but it provides the ability to run rules if an AppleScript condition is passed, i.e. `return true`.

Judging from the screenshot below, I think it works if `length of theFile > 30*60 seconds: return true` *(pseudo code)*.

[image]

I'm not however sure how to accomplish this via AppleScript. Any ideas how to do it, or where to start? A search online didn't provide many basic ideas, but it seems to be possible.

---

*Note*: Giving advice on AppleScripts is outside the scope of the Hazel support AFAIK, so I can't get any help from them.

Comment: I don't have Hazel, so I can't test with it and why a comment vs. an answer, however here's an AppleScript `do shell script` _command_ that will set `theResult` to `true` or `false` if you can figure out how to pass it `theFileName`: `set theResult to (do shell script "[[ $(afinfo -r '" & theFileName & "' | awk '/estimated duration:/{print int($3/60)}') -gt 30 ]] && echo 'true' || echo 'false'") as boolean`. You can then add this line after it, `return theResult` and it will be equivalent to `return true` or `return false` accordingly.

Comment: @user3439894 I understand why you didn't post this as an answer, but I still think you should because doing so prevents the OP from deleting the question (for whatever reason). And, in this case, your answer is likely to lead to a solution that helps others. :)

Comment: @Monomeeth, I went ahead and downloaded Hazel and after a slight modification, validated the _code_ in my comment. By the way, I do not believe that adding an answer can stop the author of the OP from deleting his/her question.

Comment: @Winterflags, I've update the answer to add info on how to make it faster, read the section at the end of the answer after: "If you want the _content_ of `do shell script` _command_ to run faster, then use the following:"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I've downloaded Hazel and tested the following AppleScript *code* on a New Rule to validate it works. The following *code* when used in an *embedded script* will set `theResult` to `true` on `theFile`, an audio file that is longer than 30 minutes. Any file 30 minutes or less, or a non-audio file will set `theResult` to `false`:

```
set theResult to (do shell script "[[ $(afinfo -r '" & POSIX path of theFile & "' | awk '/estimated duration:/{print int($3/60)}') -gt 30 ]] && echo 'true' || echo 'false'") as boolean
return theResult
```

- Note that from my first comment before posting this answer, I've changed `theFileName` to `POSIX path of theFile`, and as you can see in the image below, it validated the rule. It then also processed the rule, as I defined it, successfully.
- To change the number of minutes, change the *value* on the right side of the *operator*, e.g.
   `-gt 30` to the desired time, e.g. `-gt 20`. The *operator* can also be changed to any one of the following: `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt` or `-ge`

[image: Hazel Preference Pane]

Understanding, a little bit, the content of the `do shell script` *command*:

- `afinfo` doesn't have much in the way of an *manual page*, so just type `afinfo` in Terminal and press *enter* for its *options*.
- `afinfo -r` - `{-r --real} get the estimated duration after obtaining the real packet count`
- Example output of `afinfo -r`:

  ```
   $ afinfo -r '09 Karn Evil 9.mp3'
   File:           09 Karn Evil 9.mp3
   File type ID:   MPG3
   Num Tracks:     1
  ----
   Data format:     2 ch,  44100 Hz, '.mp3' (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1152 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame
                      no channel layout.
   audio bytes: 85117515
   audio packets: 81460
   estimated duration: 2127.935 sec
   bit rate: 320000 bits per second
   packet size upper bound: 1052
   maximum packet size: 1045
   audio data file offset: 275530
   optimized
  ----
   $
  ```

  - The above output gets piped (`|`) to `awk`.
- `awk '/estimated duration:/{print int($3/60)}'`

  - `awk` finds the *record* (line) containing `estimated duration:` in the *output* of `afinfo` piped to it and prints the third *field*, `$3`, `2127.935` as an integer, having been divided by `60` to get the number of minutes, as the time value is in seconds. In the example *output*, `awk` returned: `35`
- `$(...)` The *command substitution* portion passed `35` to the test `[[ $(...) -gt 30 ]]`, so it equated to `[[ 35 -gt 30 ]]` and as a result, using logical operators, echoed `true`. Had the value been equal to or less than 30, or a non-audio file, it would have echoed `false`.

---

If you want the *content* of `do shell script` *command* to run faster, then use the following:

```
set theResult to (do shell script "[[ $(afinfo -b '" & POSIX path of theFile & "' | awk 'FNR == 3 {print int($1/60)}') -gt 30 ]] && echo 'true' || echo 'false'") as boolean
return theResult
```

- `afinfo -b` - `{-b --brief} print a brief (one line) description of the audio file`

  - This runs faster then using `-r` as it's not counting the packets, but getting the info from embedded data. Note that while the *help* says "(one line)", the *output* is actually three lines, but still faster then the long form, especially if not using `-r`.
- Example *output* of `afinfo -b`:

  ```
  $ afinfo -b '09 Karn Evil 9.mp3'
  09 Karn Evil 9.mp3, MPG3, Num Tracks:     1
  ----
  2127.938 sec, format:   2 ch,  44100 Hz, '.mp3' (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1152 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame
  $
  ```

  - The above output gets piped (`|`) to `awk`.
- `awk 'FNR == 3 {print int($1/60)}'`

  - `awk` prints the first *field* (`$1`) of the third *record* (line) of *output* piped from `afinfo -b`, `2127.935` as an integer, having been divided by `60` to get the number of minutes, as the time value is in seconds. In the example output, `awk` returned: `35`

Comment: +1 Nice work! I'm sure others will find this useful to know. :)

Comment: @Monomeeth, so as to live up to your gracious comment,  I updated the answer to include a little bit of an understanding of what the `do shell script` _command_ is doing. BTW +1 for you on the Community Moderator Election! :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and especially for adding context and explanation which I think will be most beneficial for a wider audience!